# Return rows based on WHERE clause unless another column is NULL

Tags: mysql, select

I'd like to return every `row` that matches the `WHERE clause` and doesn't have `column2` as `NULL`.

**Query:**

```
    SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE (DATE(dateColumn)=curdate()
       AND column1='something'
       OR column1='somethingElse')
ORDER BY column1
```

This returns all the `rows` that match either of the two provided conditions for `column1`.

What would the query that includes `column2` **not null** as a condition look like?

Comment: try `IS NOT NULL`  as  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE (DATE(dateColumn)=curdate() AND column1='something' OR column1='somethingElse') and column2 is not null ORDER BY column1
`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra Sheesh. Blatantly obvious now -_-. Thanks! Care to make it an answer so I can accept for you? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IS NULL` to check the second column:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE
    DATE(dateColumn) = CURDATE() AND
    column1 IN ('something', 'somethingElse') AND
    column2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    column1;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `IS NOT NULL` as below

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (DATE(dateColumn)=curdate() AND column1='something' OR column1='somethingElse') AND column2 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY column1
```